# Not able to set proxy port in my vue js app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, proxy, vuejs2, axios

I am working on a web app using [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js) as a UI and [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) as server. Vue is running on port `8080` and Node.js is running on `3001`, so to to make API calls I am using a proxy which is not working as expected.

The below code in my `vue.config.js` is used for the proxy:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '^/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost:3001',
                ws: true,
                secure: false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And below is my Home page file which will call the URL using `axios`

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      categories: []
    }
  },
  created () {
    axios.get('/api/v1/categories')
      .then(res => {
        debugger
        this.categories = res.data
      })
  }
}
```

As I am a new to [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js), I don't know what is going wrong.

**EDIT**
This is the error I am getting:

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/v1/categories from localhost:8080 to http://localhost:3001/.
>   See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).

Comment: Are you seeing any requests hit 3001?

Comment: @skirtle yup it throws error on my terminal as `Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/v1/categories from localhost:8080 to http://localhost:3001/.

See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).`

Comment: But what about the server running on port 3001? What do the logs/terminal for that say? Are you able to hit that server directly from the browser?

Comment: @skirtle no in network tab there is no api shown there, I don't know why

Comment: The server on 3001 is running, right? Try hitting `http://localhost:3001` directly from your browser by typing it into the address bar. I repeat, what do the logs/terminal for that say?

Comment: on running  `http://localhost:3001` I am getting this on page `Cannot GET /`, I didn't get this `what do the logs/terminal for that say?`

Comment: Your node server does not seem to be running (connection reset).

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 when I do node index.js it shows app is running on port 3001 in my console

Comment: Also if you open `http://localhost:3001/` in the browser?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 no that time it says  `Cannot GET /` on browser

Comment: So, your node server is not running properly. You need to fix that first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199564/discussion-between-dheeraj-kumar-and-ssc-hrep3).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem, solved it by replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1, then with [::1]

A few months later, i had to go back to 127.0.0.1…
Maybe did some process change my **hosts** file.

You should type **ping localhost** in your terminal in order to check your current configuration and use the result to set your proxy.

Comment: Why the IP is so important? Vue and Webpack document all provide 'localhost' example, but only 127.0.0.1 works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
module.exports = { 
  devServer: { 
    proxy: { 
      '/api': { 
        target: 'http://localhost:3001', 
        ws: true, 
        secure: false 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Also, check whether you have set a base path for axios. If so, please remove api from the axios call since base path will also get added to the axios call.